# Calculating clock cycles when forwarding

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture, forwarding

I don't quite get the principle of forwarding, so I need some help. I have this file and need to calculate how many processor clocks are required to finish the program. Program completion occurs when the instruction labeled “done:” completely traverses the pipeline for the first time

---

```
00000000 1 02008025    #         or  $s0,$s0,$zero   // s0 = 0
00000004 1 02609825    #         or  $s3,$s3,$zero   // s3 = 0 (offset to data array)
00000008 1 0280a025    #         or  $s4,$s4,$zero   // s4 = 0 (sum)
0000000c 1 8C150008    #         lw  $s5,max_loops($zero) // $s5 = max_loops
00000010 1 8c110000    #         lw  $s1,one($zero)  // s1 = one;
00000014 1 8c120004    #         lw  $s2,four($zero) // s2 = four;
00000018 1 0215402a    #         slt $t0,$s0,$s5     // while ($s0<$s3)
0000001c 1 02118020    # loop:   add $s0, $s0, $s1   // s0 = s0+1
00000020 1 11000006    #         beq $t0,$zero,done  
00000024 1 8e69000C    #         lw  $t1,data($s3)   // $t1 = data[s3/4]
00000028 1 02729820    #         add $s3, $s3, $s2   // s3 = s3 + 4  
0000002c 1 0290a020    #         add $s4,$s4,$s0
00000030 1 0289a020    #         add $s4,$s4,$t1     // sum = (2*s0) + data[i]
00000034 1 08000007    #         j   loop
00000038 1 0215402a    #         slt $t0,$s0,$s5     // while ($s0<$s3)
0000003c 1 0800000f    # done:   j   done
00000040 1 00000000    #         nop
00000000 0 00000001    # one:       dw  1
00000004 0 00000004    # four:      dw  4
00000008 0 00000020    # max_loops: dw  32
0000000C 0 00000001    # data:
00000010 0 00000002
00000014 0 00000003
00000018 0 00000004
0000001c 0 00000005
00000020 0 00000006
00000024 0 00000007
00000028 0 00000008
0000002c 0 00000009
00000030 0 0000000a
00000034 0 0000000b
00000038 0 0000000c
0000003c 0 0000000d
00000040 0 0000000e
00000044 0 0000000f
00000048 0 00000010
0000004c 0 00000011
00000050 0 00000012
00000054 0 00000013
00000058 0 00000014
0000005c 0 00000015
00000060 0 00000016
00000064 0 00000017
00000068 0 00000018
0000006c 0 00000019
00000070 0 0000001a
00000074 0 0000001b
00000078 0 0000001c
0000007c 0 0000001d
00000080 0 0000001e
00000084 0 0000001f
00000088 0 00000020
```

Comment: Can you use some tools like perf? Are they available on the machine you are running?

Comment: Forwarding doesn't cost any cycles.  Stalls cost, but all the potential RAW stall hazards are covered in that code sequence (reads are sufficiently separated from writes).  The only issue is going to be control hazards.

Comment: Btw, `or  $s0,$s0,$zero` doesn't c;lear `$s0` — that is a `no-op`.  To clear `$s0`, we would do `or $s0, $zero, $zero` — see the difference?

Comment: @ErikEidt: when you edit, don't forget to remove tags that don't apply.  This isn't a [c++] question; using C++ notation for the pseudo-code in asm comments doesn't mean that people who only know C++ are going to be able to answer it, or would want to see it if they're following the [c++] tag.  Also the usage guidance on [forwarding] discourages using it because it's ambiguous, so [cpu-architecture] should get added.